Is there a way to read the chinese as pinyin

Possible Duplicate:
Should we include pinyin? 

I can't really make much out of symbols, and don't know about learning thousands of symbols. So most of the time, I rely on pinyin, because I'll primarily be speaking the language (a with your wife thing).
It's not that I can't bother myself to learn the written language, but it seems a little discouraging.
So if there's any way to view both the symbols and the pinyin on these posts, they'll be more helpful for me.

I'm voting to close since I think there is already a question on the matter. :)

Seems like a duplicate to me as well - I've also voted to close.
